# How to Concatenate in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation

In SQL Server 2012, I'm trying to select mutiple columns and concatenate them as below.

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.TITLE, ''))) + 
' ' + 
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.FIRSTNAME, ''))) + 
' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.SURNAME, ''))) AS 'Full Name',
```

The problem I have is that if the first column 'TITLE' is NULL or Blank then the next column 'FIRSTNAME' starts with a space due to the concatination.

Any ideas?

P.S - This is my first question so apologies if I have done anything wrong....

Comment: add LTRIM to whole field i.e. for Full Name

Comment: Where is the CASE statement described in the header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose whole one within `LTRIM(`

```
LTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.TITLE, ''))) + 
' ' + 
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.FIRSTNAME, ''))) + 
' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.SURNAME, '')))) AS 'Full Name',
```

Comment: This will add two spaces if firstname is null

Answer (score 1):

You could just solve that problem using `ltrim()` around the entire expression:

```
LTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.TITLE, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.FIRSTNAME, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.SURNAME, '')))) AS [Full Name],
```

Helpful hint:  don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Although this sometimes works, at other times, the code will not do what you expect.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

There are other methods, such as adding the space before the test for NULL

```
(COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Title)) + ' ', '') +
 COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(S.FirstName)) + ' ', '') +
 COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(s.SurName)), '')
)
```

This has the advantage of handling the double spaces if there is no first name. However, you will need an `rtrim()` for the entire expression to handle no surname.

Comment: Your first answer will add two spaces if firstname is null

Comment: @kaf . . . Not only is that not mentioned in the question and a "feature" of the accepted answer, but this answer is the only one that addresses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below. I have omitted `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` for clarity. And using `COALESCE()` insted `ISNULL()`

```
SELECT
   COALESCE( s.Title + ' ', '') + COALESCE( s.Firstname + ' ', '') +
   + COALESCE( s.surname, '')
```

Use trimming within `COALESCE()`. For example;

```
COALESCE( LTRIM(RTRIM( s.Title)) + ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved very easy by using [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CONCAT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) which was introduced in sqlserver 2012.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(S.TITLE)) + ' ', 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(S.FIRSTNAME)) + ' ', 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(S.SURNAME))) AS [Full Name]
FROM ..
```